# Groovlet + Tomcat: "unable to resolve class" when importing libraries

Tags: groovy, groovlet

I'm having some trouble running a groovy servlet (groovlet) in tomcat that imports a library class. When I don't import anything the groovlet works correctly, but if I do import something that I expect to be on the classpath (I can import the same class successfully in a regular servlet), I see the following error:

```
groovy.util.ScriptException: Could not parse scriptName: /MyGroovlet.groovy
java.lang.RuntimeException: groovy.util.ScriptException: Could not parse scriptName: /MyGroovlet.groovy
    at groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet$1.call(GroovyServlet.java:123)
...
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, /MyGroovlet.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.mycompany.mypackage.MyLibraryClass
 @ line 1, column 1.
```

The jar containing `MyLibraryClass` is in `shared/lib`, which is loaded by tomcat by the following in `catalina.properties`:

```
shared.loader=...,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar,...
```

My groovlets are mapped as described in the [user guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets) in my application's `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here's the code for the groovlet, `MyGroovlet.groovy`:

```
import com.mycompany.mypackage.MyLibraryClass
MyLibraryClass.someStaticMethod()
```

My groovlet is deployed to `WEB-INF/groovy/MyGroovlet.groovy`, per the [GroovyServlet API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/servlet/GroovyServlet.html).

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/myapplication/MyGroovlet.groovy`, the error described previously is written to my application logs.

Is there some way that I need to explicitly declare the runtime classpath for GroovyServlet? I've tried moving the library jar to several places, including `WEB-INF/lib` and moving the actual `MyLibraryClass.class` file to `WEB-INF/classes`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Groovy plugin for Eclipse. Exporting Groovlets in a war file does also work.

When I do export my Groovlet-based application, this helpful plugin puts .groovy files in the /WEB-INF/classes directory (in the classpath). And it works when I deploy the war file in my Tomcat Server.

Hope that this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm not 100% sure this addresses the problem I'm having. If you do export the application from within Eclipse using the plugin, you're saying that you're able to import and use external (presumably java) libraries? It's not that I'm having trouble exporting and...

Comment: ...deploying, it's that when I do deploy, I get errors with imported files. See the 'caused by' portion of the stack trace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid mistake I made was that I needed to reload the webapp before the jar I copied into WEB-INF/lib would be loaded (i.e. either restarting entire Tomcat server, or reload just the specific app from the Tomcat manager).  Dynamically editing the .groovy files right inside the Tomcat/webapps/ dir and seeing the updates to pages immediately lulled me into the feeling that everything would be auto-loaded, but not so with jars.  It was maddening until I realized what was going on.